# Unable to find link element in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using selenium driver in python.
I am trying to find and click a link web element located inside a dropdown menu.
I used ActionChains to click and expand the dropdown menu and it works.
But i am unable to find the link element and click on it. Upon clicking it will trigger a mail.
I have used all find_element_by methods but nothing works.

[image: html code]

The code which i have used till now. It results in the No Element found error.

```
optionsmenu = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/table/tbody/tr/td[5]/a')
 

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(optionsmenu)
actions.click()
actions.perform()

print ('Options menu clicked')

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="userOptionsMenu"]/td/ul/li[5]/a/span[2]').click()
```

Answer (score 1):

The desired element is a [React](https://reactjs.org/) element so to click on the element you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "li.icon.Email > a span[data-bind$='resendWelcomeEmail']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='icon Email']/a//span[contains(@data-bind, 'resendWelcomeEmail')]"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But both option causes timeout exception.

Comment: It's much better to use WebDriverWait! in my answer I was pointing out the structure of the XPath was not good, and recommended to use a CSS selector.